# How do bunkers work in Risk Legacy?

Tags: risk-legacy

What are the dice modifiers for bunkers in Risk Legacy? Can you give some examples of dice rolls and how they are modified by the presence of a bunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunker adds 1 to the highest defender's die as long as it is less than 6. For example, a defender's roll of 4+3 becomes 5+3; 5+5 becomes 6+5, 6+1 stays 6+1, and 2 becomes 3 (the case where you're only rolling one die).

Note that this roughly flips the normal attacker's advantage - ordinarily, as long as both sides are rolling max dice, the attacker loses 0.9 units and the defender loses 1.1 on average, but with a bunker it's 1.1 and 0.9 the other way.

Comment: Someone should check me on the rules - I can't find printed rules so I'm inferring the rules (and computing the odds) from an old program I wrote instead.

Comment: You are correct about the modification to the roll. Page 11 of [the rules.](http://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/dad2886d1c4311ddbd0b0800200c9a66/00D721465056900B10A16E11F8F54E7F.pdf)